# Can't complete Windows XP installation on Samsung Series 9

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, windows-installation

I just bought a [Samsung Series 9](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/laptops/NP900X3A-A03US) laptop, and I want to install Windows XP on it. It's supposed to support Windows XP and there are Windows XP drivers on its product page.

I've installed Windows XP on many computers before so I'm generally familiar with the process, but this one is stumping me.

I deleted the existing pre-installed Windows 7 partitions (after backing them up) and then put the Windows XP disc in my external CD drive and booted from it. The blue installation screen came up, and after a while seemed to have completed copying files to the HD successfully.

But the hard-drive won't boot in order to continue the Windows XP installation. I just get a black screen with a blinking cursor.

I tried enabling and disabling AHCI. I tried enabling and disabling UEFI booting. I looked at the partition with Disk Director and confirmed it has an `ntldr` file. But I couldn't get it to work.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: You can't just enable and disable AHCI mid-install, you need to pick one and stick with it. If you're installing in AHCI you may need a driver.

Comment: How do I get (and use) a driver?

Comment: That would come from Samsung.

Comment: I looked here but couldn't find it: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads/NP900X3A-A03US

Comment: You need to use a tool like [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/) on your Windows XP disc (or .ISO file).  You can use it to slipstream your chipset drivers so they load with the Windows installation.  After you do, I would keep AHCI enabled (make sure the RAID settings are correct or disabled), and unless you need it, I would disable UEFI booting.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm familiar with nLite, but I couldn't find the drivers for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by running Windows XP's install disc, typing `R` for the Recovery Console, and using `fixmbr`.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

- Change the mode in the BIOS from AHCI to IDE
- Buy Windows XP SATA (like Windows XP, but includes SATA drivers) (this is the better option)